# R: how to select only continuous numeric columns

Tags: r, selection, continuous

This might be more of a theory question than a coding question.

I am trying to write a shiny app that will loop through the continuous numeric columns of a data frame and perform tests on those columns. The app allows for the user to upload their own data frame, so I don't know what it will look like in advance. I know I can pick only the numeric columns in the following way with the dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
        select(where(is.numeric))
```

This works, but discrete numerical columns are kept as well. I cannot think of a good way in which to only select continuous columns.

I've thought of trying to do something like only choosing columns where the number of times the mode is repeated is less than a certain proportion of the length of the data frame. Or maybe something like the number of unique values needs to be greater than the number of times the mode is repeated. But neither of those seem like they will generalize well. And also they would not get rid of id columns.

I appreciate any ideas, thanks.

Comment: If the discrete variables are coded as integers or as factor, you would have FALSE returned if you ask `is.double`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library `schoolmath` with `is.decimal` and `is.whole` functions:

```
library(schoolmath)
x <- c(1, 1.5)
any(is.decimal(x))
TRUE
```

So you could process to your dataframe with `apply`:

```
decimal_cols <- apply(df, 2, function(x) any(is.decimal(x))
```

The index values of the returned TRUEs will be the columns with decimal values.

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about define `is_continuous`:

```
# one of them:
is_discrete   <- function(vec) all(is.numeric(x)) && all(x %% 1 == 0)
is_discrete   <- function(vec, tolerance=0.000001) all(is.numeric(x)) && all(min(abs(c(x %% 1, x %% 1 - 1))) < tolerance)

# and then:
is_continuous <- function(vec) all(is.numeric(vec)) && !is_discrete(vec)
```

And after that, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
        select(where(is_continuous))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered turning your discrete variables into factors? here is an example that might have the solution you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

head(mtcars)

> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

Then I turn cyl into a factor and then select only numeric columns apart from the factor which is cyl:

mtcars2 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  select(where( ~ !is.factor(.x) && is.numeric(.x))) %>%
  slice_head(n = 5)

# A tibble: 5 x 10
    mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21     160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2  21     160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
3  22.8   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
4  21.4   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
5  18.7   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
```

I edited my could and use only `select` function. However I assumed that your discrete variables have limited range like `cyl` here. Perhaps it would have been better if you could share a piece of your data for us to see what they are exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am writing the app to be such that the user can upload any data frame, so I would not know in advance which columns are factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
hot.deck::is.discrete( mtcars$mpg, cutoff = 7 )
hot.deck::is.discrete( mtcars$carb, cutoff = 7 )
```

Identify all vars with 7 or more levels

```
 names(mtcars)[as.logical(sapply( mtcars ,  function(X){!hot.deck::is.discrete(X , cutoff = 7 )}))]
```